# Polling storage queue for messages using console app webjob

Tags: azure, console-application, .net-core, azure-webjobs

I wanted to create a console app as a WebJob using .NET Core but the WebJobs SDK is not yet available in .NET Core.

I've been advised to handle the scenario of reading messages from Azure Storage Queue manually. Looks like all the WebJobs SDK does is to keep polling the queue anyway.

Is the following code the basic idea in doing this? It doesn't look very sophisticated but not sure how it can be more sophisticated.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   var runContinuously = true;
   while (runContinuously)
   {
      ReadAndProcessMessage();
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   };
}

private static void ReadAndProcessMessage()
{
   // Read message
   ReadMessage();

   // Process message and handle the work
   HandleWork();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That will work. And I like simplicity.

The QueueTriggerAttribute makes use of a random exponential back-off algorithm to help minimize your transaction costs. If you'd like to trace through the logic of how this is accomplished, starting with the [QueueListener](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Queues/Listeners/QueueListener.cs) class is a good way to go. Clone the project and then hop over to the RandomizedExponentialBackoffStrategy class.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So, the idea behind the WebJobs SDK's approach is to intelligently determine how often we should poll the queue by using a sophisticated algorithm as opposed to setting it to a specific interval. It's kind of like fixed cost vs variable cost decision -- polling the queue at set intervals would be the fixed cost approach which is inherently costlier.

Comment: You got it. Our particular web app is B2B, and we get very little traffic after 6:00PM Pacific time. So we've dialed up the max wait interval since there's not a lot of demand at 3:00AM.

Comment: Makes sense. My thinking then is that it probably wouldn't make a whole lot of sense for me to invest my time in re-creating this nice functionality that WebJobs SDK provides because I'm sure at some point, it will be ported to .NET Core. In the mean time, I can come up with a simple logic that says poll every 100ms during peak hours then start polling every 2 seconds. I can come up with this logic by observing traffic patterns. This will be far simpler for me to implement then to re-invent the wheel. Just trying to better utilize my time and energy.

Comment: Still, I really appreciate the link. It's totally useful and great to understand how things work under the hood.